# Calling BizTalk pipeline component from .NET C#

Tags: .net, biztalk, biztalk-pipelines

Currently decryption/encryption and signature validation is implemented in my BTS application by using custom pipeline component which internally uses pipeline assembly that is the BTS assemblies, I was thinking of shifting the message encryption/decryption logic to the web service layer so that once messages are authenticated/validated then I can send the message to the BTS application for further processing, but as the decryption/encryption is done using BTS assemblies.

Probably I need to rewrite this logic again .NET C# or is there a way I can use the same implementation on the .NET web service layer box?

So that BTS application would perform only the business process and would not have an overhead message encryption/decryption, and hence the above question

Answer (score 0):

You can always do encryption/decryption yourself using the .NET system.security.cryptography namespace: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx.
But I've always found it a little hard to use, there might be some wrappers for it on CodePlex that simplify everything.

I'm currently at a bank, and we have a WCF external web service that receives the users data via a web-service method-call.  In our case, we are using certificates and WCF handles all that (with one or two support calls with Microsoft), and IIS handles the SSL.  But you could also go PGP or any other encryption/decryption in the webservice.